# Blank page in main site after installing wordpress in subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

After installed wordpress in a subfolder, index.php in root dir shows a blank page.
Main site isn't a wordpress and has a php function in another subfolder.
I suspect is an .htaccess issue.
Any help very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Ps: console says error 500.

I tried cleaning as .htacces in wordpress subfolder as .htaccess in root folder, but nothing changed.
Here .htaccess in root folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) ?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule blog/(.*) blog/?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

And here .htaccess in wordpress subfolder /test-wp

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /test-wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test-wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you install wordpress in a subfolder, nothing will change in the root folder. I am pretty sure that your installing of wordpress is not related to the issue. Have you tried deleting the subfolder test-wp? Is the problem still there after deleting?

Comment: And even if it is related to the wordpress installation, it would be because the server software has had a hickup. Try restarting the server and see if the problem persists.

Comment: _"Here .htaccess in root folder:"_ - that IfModule block is pretty pointless, if you then place the mod_rewrite directives _outside_ of it. And your second rule, `RewriteRule blog/(.*) blog/?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]`, will of course never apply - because the previous rule with `(.*)` has matched _all_ possible requested URL paths already.

Answer (score 0):

for all that could have had this issue, I found the problem.
As commented @Klassiek effectively there is no relation between what happen in subfolder and main site.
The issue was that customer changed php version and 8.1 has deprecated a function used in main page, so blank was only because no php error was shown.
Thank you all for your time